# Terminology: Camera Tracking, Camera Relocalization

Tags: computer-vision

I am reading the paper *RGBD Datasets: Past, Present and Future* available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00999), and two terms that I am not familiar with are presented.

On page three, middle left side of the page, the author refers to

- Camera Tracking
- Camera Relocalization

From what I understand, camera tracking is when you have a sequence of 2D frames, and you track the position of an object within those frames to determine the camera's pose as it moves in space. I am wondering if this is correct?

Further, I am not sure what camera relocalization means, and some Google searching did not yield a conclusive answer. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of SLAM papers, camera tracking means "local relative pose estimation of different views of the scene viewed by a given camera". It's also called *visual odometry*. What is important in this task is to get accurate estimates of from-to-frame (or in a small time window) camera displacements. It's to make a difference with mapping where you have global map optimization applied (think loop closures or global bundle adjustment). I refer you to the [PTAM](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Egk/PTAM/) paper for more details as to why these 2 tasks are considered.

Relocalization means your robot has a map of a known environment, then you kidnap and blind it, and when you uncover its sensors you want it to recognize what is its new position with respect to the map it already knew (you did not bring it to an unknown place).

Comment: When you say local pose estimation in line 1 of your answer, do you mean of the objects in the scene, or of the camera?

Comment: @IntegrateThis the quantity to be estimated is the camera pose (position + orientation). Local means in the vicinity of a nearby or recent other camera position as opposed to global (in an absolute map of the overall space).